# How to make a figure leave less space from top?

Tags: beamer, columns

I have 2 columns in a beamer frame. The first one on the left contains a picture while the second, on the right, an enumerate.

```
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=4cm]{java5.pdf}
                \caption{Our own test of downsampling}
                \label{fig:3}
                \end{figure}
        \end{column}
```

the figure looks akwardly to start 5% of frame size below the same level enumerate starts in neighboring column.

How to get them to same level?

Comment: Try to use option `[T]` for the `columns` environment. See 12.7 Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns in the beamer user guide.

Comment: I am using it in my code.

Comment: Could you report a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with just that frame? This will help in understanding the problem and giving you the right answer.

Comment: If you want to optically align a figure with a displayed list you may need manual tweaking, for example `\vspace*{-1cm}`  just after `\begin{figure}` would move it up

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Make that an answer please.

Answer (score 35):

If you want to optically align a figure with a displayed list you may need manual tweaking, for example `\vspace*{-1cm}` just after `\begin{figure}` would move it up.

Comment: Just wanted to add that depending on your needs, you may need to adjust as far back as -4cm (e.g., when plotting a group plot on a single page).